# Accessing the Terminal on a 2008 MacBook Pro, when booting in single-user mode

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, dual-boot, single-user

I am booting my 2008 MacBook Pro into single-user mode and attempting to access the Terminal by using the key combination <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> during startup. But it doesn't appear to be working. Pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> takes me to the login screen.

I am attempting to access the Terminal by following the instructions mentioned in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fsK5tIAz6A) tutorial.

How do I get access to the Terminal? I have a dual boot system with both macOS and Windows installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When booting into [single-user mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201573), continue holding the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> key combination until you see white text scrolling on the screen.

Once the text stops scrolling, a prompt is presented where you can enter commands. If the prompt doesn't appear after the text has stopped scrolling, try pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: I need to do a password reset procedure, and in the tutorial asks for access to the terminal at startup, accessing this way you described, the effect is the same?

Comment: @FelipeDuarte Kindly [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/334853/edit) your question and share the link to the tutorial that you are following.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Wouldn't pressing `Shift-Command-U` be quicker?  And even quicker would be `Command-Space` and then typing "Terminal"?

Comment: @FelipeDuarte You are attempting to boot into Singe user mode. Press and hold Command + S during startup. You'll see a scroll display of text. Once that comes to a still, press enter key (press enter twice if required). You'll be presented with the command prompt. See if that works.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Command + S at startup has no effect, it alerts  "Beep ", but does not enter the terminal, is it possible to enter the Singe mode manually?

Comment: @FelipeDuarte It appears you have not entered single-user mode correctly. Turn off your MacBook. Now press the power button and immediately press and hold Command + s key combination. Instead of going to login screen, your MacBook will boot into single-user mode.

Comment: It worked, it occurs that I have Windows and the Mac installed, and I have to press Command + S before selecting the OS, thanks!